# How to tighten up mesh before subsurface mod added

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm modelling this detail and when I add the subsurface mod, it does odd things.  I cant make any loop cuts on it for some reason so have to use the knife tool.  Would I have to add alot of cuts to be able to get a clean looking mesh... any help on where to make cuts without creating ngons?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You already created Ngons which is why no loopcuts can be added (works only on 4 sided faces) and also why Subsurf creates artifacts - it doesn't go well with Ngons

Answer (score 0):

Select the edges you want to tighten and hit ctrl-b.